# Can i change progress bar style (likes stripes ) of eclipse progress bar?

Tags: eclipse, swt, splash-screen

Can i change progress bar style (likes stripes ) of eclipse progress bar like below ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `ProgressBar` SWT control only supports a `SWT.SMOOTH` style flag which is unlikely to give this look - on some platforms it doesn't do anything at all.

The look of the progress bar depends a lot on the native control used on each platform and can vary quite a lot.